# Returning joined columns from different tables using JPA native query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Below are the mapped entities : Camapaign -> Question -> Choice

```
@Entity
public class Campaign
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long campaignId;
    
    private String campaignName;
    private String  campaignDescription;
    private int noOfQuestions;
    private int noOfChoices;
    private Date lastUpdatedTime;
    private Date createdTime;
    private boolean isActivated;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "campaign",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Question> questions;
```

```
@Entity
public class Question
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long questionId;
    
    private String question;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Choice> choices;
    
    private String correctAnswer;
    
    private String correctAnswerDescription;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CAMPAIGN_ID")
    private Campaign campaign;
```

```
@Entity
public class Choice
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long choiceId;
    
    private String choice;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="QUESTION_ID")
    private Question question;
```

And another mapped entities : QuizUsers -> AttendedQuestions

```
@Entity
@Table(name="quiz_users")
public class QuizUser
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long userId;
    
    private String emailId;
    private String fullName;
    private long mobileNumber;
    private long attendedCampaignId;
    private boolean isSubmittedQuiz;
    private boolean isEvaluated;
    private long correctAnswerCount; 
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quizUser",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AttendedQuestions> questions;
```

```
@Entity
public class AttendedQuestions
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private long attendedQuestionId;    
    private String answeredChoice;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private QuizUser quizUser;
```

All the entities have their respective getters and setters

Now my requirement is to join and select some of the columns by executing the following MySQL query(alternative JPQL query would be acceptable) :

```
SELECT C.campaign_id,C.campaign_name,U.full_name,U.mobile_number,
U.email_id,COUNT(Q.correct_answer) AS correct_answers
FROM campaign C INNER JOIN quiz_users U ON C.campaign_id = U.attended_campaign_id
LEFT JOIN attended_questions AQ ON U.user_id = AQ.user_id
LEFT JOIN question Q ON AQ.answered_choice = Q.correct_answer
```

This is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EvaluatedResultRepository extends JpaRepository<Campaign, Long>
{
    public static final String QUERY = "SELECT C.campaign_id,C.campaign_name,U.full_name,U.mobile_number,U.email_id,COUNT(Q.correct_answer) AS correct_answers FROM campaign C INNER JOIN quiz_users U ON C.campaign_id = U.attended_campaign_id LEFT JOIN attended_questions AQ ON U.user_id = AQ.user_id LEFT JOIN question Q ON AQ.answered_choice = Q.correct_answer";
    
    @Query(value = QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
    public Collection<EvaluatedResult> findAllEvaluatedResult();
}
```

EvaluatedResult is my DTO and I have tried making it a class or interface(with getters only) for projections and tried selecting it.

I have also tried changing the T in JpaRepository<T.. to QuizUsers but everytime it is returning :

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Please help in giving a solution. Thanks in advance

Full stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mm.service.EvaluationService.evaluateQuiz(EvaluationService.java:28) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.mm.controller.EvaluationController.evaluateQuiz(EvaluationController.java:22) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at com.mm.config.AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthTokenFilter.java:52) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
```

Edit : I am able to get the result of the query in MySQL workbench.

Comment: Why not have a mapping from `QuizUser` to `Campaign` if you already have the ID? What does `EvaluatedResult` look like? And what is the (full) stacktrace to the exception?

Comment: Because QuizUser attendedCampaignId is being selected with Campaign campaignId.

Comment: Whats the code of `EvaluationService.evaluateQuiz()`? That is where the error occurs

Comment: return evaluatedRepo.findAllEvaluatedResult(); @XtremeBaumer

Comment: then your `evaluatedRepo` is null. That is a config error and has nothing to do with the mapping or the sql

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Is it anything wrong with the query ? The project is almost done and this is the only issue bothering me now. Thanks

Comment: That is a config error and has nothing to do with the mapping or the sql

Comment: @XtremeBaumer all other communication with the database is working fine. The query is working fine in the DB workbench. I just need to get that result in Spring Boot.

Comment: your evaluatedRepo is null. it has nothing at all to do with the query

Comment: XtremeBaumer thanks, It was really a config error. I hadn't @Autowired the repo object.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the error,
It was a simple mistake.

I didn't @Autowired evaluatedRepo.

After that the Null Pointer Exception went away.
The structure of the return JSON was messed up, so I will paste the solution here for future references for anyone else :

```
public static final String MYSQL = "SELECT C.campaign_id,C.campaign_name,C.no_of_questions,U.full_name,U.mobile_number,U.email_id,COUNT(Q.correct_answer) FROM campaign C INNER JOIN quiz_users U ON C.campaign_id = U.attended_campaign_id LEFT JOIN attended_questions AQ ON U.user_id = AQ.user_id LEFT JOIN question Q ON AQ.answered_choice = Q.correct_answer";
    
@Query(value = MYSQL,nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Object[]> findAllEvaluatedResult();
```

Service Layer processing the returned result from Repo :

```
public List<EvaluatedResult> evaluateQuiz(long campaignId)
{
        List<EvaluatedResult> evaluatedResults = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object[]> joinedResults = null;
        
        
        joinedResults = evaluatedRepo.findAllEvaluatedResult();
        List<QuizUser> quizUsers = quizUserRepo.findByAttendedCampaignId(campaignId);
        
        for(Object[] array : joinedResults)
        {
            EvaluatedResult eR = new EvaluatedResult();
            eR.setCampaignId(bigIntToLong(array[0]+""));
            eR.setCampaignName((String)array[1]);
            eR.setNumberOfQuestions((int)array[2]);
            eR.setFullName((String)array[3]);
            eR.setMobileNumber(bigIntToLong(array[4]+""));
            eR.setEmailId((String)array[5]);
            eR.setCorrectAnswers(bigIntToLong(array[6]+""));
            
            evaluatedResults.add(eR);
        }
        return evaluatedResults;
}
    
private long bigIntToLong(String num)
{
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(num);
    long campaignId = bigInt.longValue();
    return campaignId;
}
```

I made a simple mistake and it was resolved